# While working on my project, a problem appeared in the code

Tags: python, sqlite, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

While working on my project, a problem appeared in the code. I am working on my school project and discovered a problem where the telegram API does not allow sending one part of the messages when other, larger ones are being quietly sent.

My mistake completely looks like this -

```
2024-03-17 00:01:25,850 (__init__.py:1147 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message caption is too long"
2024-03-17 00:01:25,852 (__init__.py:1149 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Василий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1141, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Василий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 149, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Василий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 92, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\project\project_code\main.py", line 178, in list_of_legs_exercises
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, exercise_image, exercise_description)
  File "C:\Users\Василий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 2125, in send_photo
    apihelper.send_photo(
  File "C:\Users\Василий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 496, in send_photo
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, files=files, method='post')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Василий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 164, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Василий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 191, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message caption is too long
```

Here is my code in full -

```
import telebot 
from telebot import types
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image
import io

class Exercise:
    def __init__(self, db_path):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path, check_same_thread=False)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def get_legs_exercise_image_by_id(self, exercise_id):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT image FROM exercises_legs WHERE id=?", (exercise_id))
        exercise_image = self.cur.fetchone()
    
        if exercise_image is not None:
            image_data = exercise_image[0]
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
            return image
        else:
            return None
    
    def get_back_exercise_image_by_id(self, exercise_id):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT image FROM exercises_back WHERE id=?", (exercise_id))
        exercise_image = self.cur.fetchone()
    
        if exercise_image is not None:
            image_data = exercise_image[0]
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
            return image
        else:
            return None
    
    def get_legs_exercise_description_by_id(self, exercise_id):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT description FROM exercises_legs WHERE id=?", (exercise_id))
        description = self.cur.fetchone()
        return description
    
    def get_back_exercise_description_by_id(self, exercise_id):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT description FROM exercises_back WHERE id=?", (exercise_id))
        description = self.cur.fetchone()
        return description
    
    def get_legs_exercise_image_by_availability(self, exercise_availability):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT image FROM exercises_legs WHERE availability == ?", (exercise_availability))
        exercise_images = self.cur.fetchall()
        if exercise_images is not None:
            return exercise_images
        else:
            return None
        
    def get_back_exercise_image_by_availability(self, exercise_availability):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT image FROM exercises_back WHERE availability == ?", (exercise_availability))
        exercise_images = self.cur.fetchall()
        if exercise_images is not None:
            return exercise_images
        else:
            return None
            
    def get_legs_exercise_description_by_availability(self, exercise_availability):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT description FROM exercises_legs WHERE availability == ?", (exercise_availability))
        descriptions = self.cur.fetchall()
        return descriptions
    
    def get_back_exercise_description_by_availability(self, exercise_availability):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT description FROM exercises_back WHERE availability == ?", (exercise_availability))
        descriptions = self.cur.fetchall()
        return descriptions


    def add_exercise(self, title, image, description, group_muscle, difficulty, availability, energy_cost):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO exercises(title, image, description, group_muscle, difficulty, availability,) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (title, image, description, group_muscle, difficulty, availability, energy_cost))
        self.conn.commit()

    def update_exercise(self, exercise_id, title, image, description, group_muscle, difficulty, availability, energy_cost):
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE exercises SET title=?, image=?, description=?, group_muscle=?, difficulty=?, availability=? WHERE id=?", (title, image, description, group_muscle, difficulty, availability, energy_cost, exercise_id))
        self.conn.commit()

    def delete_exercise(self, exercise_id):
        self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM exercises WHERE id=?", (exercise_id,))
        self.conn.commit()

    def close_connection(self):
        self.conn.close()



db_path = 'exercises_data.db'
exercise_manager = Exercise(db_path)



token = '7031939959:AAFOYF-nB-3_37yvr0Q7cXT1NnAf3MW-yvw'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_menu(message):
    markup =types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    butn1=types.KeyboardButton('Каталог упражнений')
    butn2=types.KeyboardButton('Информация о боте')
    markup.row(butn1, butn2)
    welcome_text = 'Здравствуйте, этот бот - ваш персональный фитнесс ассистент, он сможет помочь вам в подборе тренировочного плана и упражнений'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, welcome_text, reply_markup=markup)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def aft_click1(message):

    if message.text == 'Информация о боте':
        markup =types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        butn_back=types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
        bot_information_text = 'Здравствуйте, этот бот - ваш персональный фитнесс ассистент, он сможет помочь вам в подборе тренировочного плана и упражнений.\n\nЭтот бот создат в качестве итогового проекта, является всего лишь помощником и не гарантирует 100-процентного результата, если у вас имеются проблемы со здоровьем, то перед выполнением технически сложных упражнений рекомендуется проконсультироваться со специалистом.'
        markup.row(butn_back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, bot_information_text, reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Каталог упражнений':
        markup =types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        butn1=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на ноги')
        butn2=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на спину')
        butn3=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на пресс')
        butn4=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на грудные мышцы')
        butn5=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на руки')
        butn6=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на плечи')
        butn7=types.KeyboardButton('Кардио упражнения')
        butn_back=types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
        markup.row(butn1, butn2)
        markup.row(butn3, butn4)
        markup.row(butn5, butn6)
        markup.row(butn7, butn_back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Выберете желаемый тип упражнений по группам мышц', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        markup =types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        butn1=types.KeyboardButton('Каталог упражнений')
        butn2=types.KeyboardButton('Информация о боте')
        markup.row(butn1, butn2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Назад', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Назад к типам упражнений':
        markup =types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        butn1=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на ноги')
        butn2=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на спину')
        butn3=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на пресс')
        butn4=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на грудные мышцы')
        butn5=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на руки')
        butn6=types.KeyboardButton('Упражнения на плечи')
        butn7=types.KeyboardButton('Кардио упражнения')
        butn_back=types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
        markup.row(butn1, butn2)
        markup.row(butn3, butn4)
        markup.row(butn5, butn6)
        markup.row(butn7, butn_back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Назад к типам упражнений', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Упражнения на ноги':
        markup =types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        butn1=types.KeyboardButton('Нет никакого инвентаря')
        butn2=types.KeyboardButton('Есть гантели или гири')
        butn3=types.KeyboardButton('Хожу в тренажерный зал')
        butn_back=types.KeyboardButton('Назад к типам упражнений')
        markup.row(butn1, butn2, butn3)
        markup.row(butn_back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Выберите тип вашего инвентаря', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, list_of_legs_exercises)


def list_of_legs_exercises(message):
    if message.text == 'Нет никакого инвентаря':
        exercise_images = exercise_manager.get_legs_exercise_image_by_availability(('1'))
        exercise_descriptions = exercise_manager.get_legs_exercise_description_by_availability(('1'))
        x = 0 
        for i in exercise_images:
            exercise_image = i[0]
            exercise_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(exercise_image))
            exercise_description = exercise_descriptions[x]
            x+=1
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, exercise_image, exercise_description)
    elif message.text == 'Есть гантели или гири':
        exercise_images = exercise_manager.get_legs_exercise_image_by_availability(('2'))
        exercise_descriptions = exercise_manager.get_legs_exercise_description_by_availability(('2'))
        y = 0 
        for i in exercise_images:
            exercise_image = i[0]
            exercise_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(exercise_image))
            exercise_description = exercise_descriptions[y]
            y+=1
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, exercise_image, exercise_description)
    if message.text == 'Хожу в тренажерный зал':
        exercise_images = exercise_manager.get_legs_exercise_image_by_availability(('3'))
        exercise_descriptions = exercise_manager.get_legs_exercise_description_by_availability(('3'))
        z = 0 
        for i in exercise_images:
            exercise_image = i[0]
            exercise_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(exercise_image))
            exercise_description = exercise_descriptions[z]
            z+=1
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, exercise_image, exercise_description)


    
bot.polling(none_stop= True)
```

I tried to reduce the amount of text, although it did not violate the limits anyway, it reduced the database - it did not help

Comment: Too much code; can you make a [mcve]? Error says "message caption is too long", did you check how much you try to post? Do you try to cram your whole message in the caption when it should go into a message body, or whatever Telegram calls it?

Comment: I addressed the capture parameter, the text did not exceed 1000 characters, other messages were sent quietly, and only on this it was interrupted.